# Copying a lot of large files in windows 7 doesn't work

Tags: windows-7, windows, copy-paste

Im trying to copy a TB worth of files to another hard drive, from a RAID5 array. I select all folders, copy, and paste to the drive. Except nothing happens. It wont do more than 50-70 folders of files at a time. Thats pretty ridiculous.

Comment: How big are these files? Have you tried a different program, like Total Commander, or TeraCopy? I'd even suggest RichCopy from Microsoft.

Comment: yeah stay away from using Explorer for something like this - always seems to have problems.  Try RoboCopy, XCopy, or equivalents.

Comment: The problem is, my data set is 3.8GB I have to put them on 4 drives (1 connected at a time via esata). So I have to copy portions to each drive. I tried using winrar and simply save to the empty drive, with split files, but it also locks up.

Comment: Tried RichCopy, and its REALLY slow.

Comment: Sorry meant 3.8TB. The files range from 1mb to 15GB each.

Comment: This silent failure to paste can also happen when you have corrupted file(s) or folder(s)

Answer (score 3):

Normally this should not happen.
However if you are interested in getting the files copied rather than getting to the bottom of it, try using robocopy.

1) press Win-R

2) type cmd and press enter

3) in the command prompt type robocopy [src] [dst] (replace [src] and [dst] with source and destination directory paths)

Comment: Whoa, there are really Windows 7 users that still use the “Run” dialog?

Comment: @Johannes Rossel:  oh yeah.  I use it all the time!  nice and simple!

Comment: @stu: The search box in the start menu is a proper superset of the “Run” dialog, so I never felt the need of using it anymore.

Comment: Its fairly slow. In the explorer copy/paste Im getting around 60-80 MB/s. Here Im getting 1/2 to 1/3 of that speed.

Comment: +1 for robocopy although I would possibly use xcopy myself for simpler jobs and include the /v and /z flags for verify and re-startable mode.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a 3rd party application until it's solved. I found [Total Commander](http://www.ghisler.com), a shareware file manager, it can do the copy works fast and flawless.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try [TeraCopy](http://www.codesector.com/teracopy.php).  I use it all the time to manage copying of lots of large files on Windows.